# Highcharts with VB.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, highcharts

I have managed to load Highcharts using vb.net.

Can I use JavaScript code for the Highcharts as well as loading the chart from my default.aspx.vb page?

I like the functionality of writing code in my default.aspx.vb page but cannot find samples to assist with design unless I use JavaScript - can I use both?

I cannot get the download samples to work in either VS2010 or VS2013.

displaying my chart on my web page

```
<asp:Literal ID="ltrChart" runat="server">
```

On my Form_Load page

```
Dim Chart = New DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
Dim xAxis As New XAxis

xAxis.Categories = ({"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"})
Chart.SetXAxis(xAxis)

Dim ser As New Series
ser.Data = New Data(New Object() {29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4})
Chart.SetSeries(ser)

ltrChart.Text = str
```

Comment: The code that you initialize from the server side most likely initializes the chart control.  So I would say yes you can use both, but on the client you can only use the API to change values, attach to events, etc as dictated by the API.

Comment: We stopped using DotNet.Highcharts due to limited updates. Currently we use in-house classes that build the appropriate javascript and then render them to the page as registered script blocks. This makes the page dynamic in that any postback/ajax calls function with new sets of data and the front end is interactive for the user.